# Run ls -lrt and use the file

Tags: shell, unix

I want to get the latest file in a directory using the `ls -lrt` command and store it in a variable and then run the rest of the code based on it.

This is my snippet:

```
LATEST_FILE=`ls -rt $INPUT_LOCATION/somefile*.utf.gz | tail -1`

**{I want to check if Latest file is valid. If Yes proceed further, if not exit}**

python mycode.py $LATEST_FILE
```

I tried this:

```
if [$LATEST_FILE = ""]
then
    echo "FIle does not exists"
    exit 0
fi
```

This works fine if the file is not present. But if the file is present, then it throws this error:

```
./script.sh[5]: [somefile123.utf.gz: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two spaces and quotation marks:

```
if [ "$LATEST_FILE" = "" ]
```

Comment: If the file is not present, It throws `]: [: argument expected` .

Comment: Did you put the quotation marks around `"$LATEST_FILE"`?

Comment: @ViChU, the reason you need spaces: `[` is a **command**, not just syntax. Like any command, it must be separated by whitespace from its arguments.

Comment: @ManuelBarbe yes the code works now. Thanks. I still see `No such file or directory` in the console which is a result of the ls command. Does it come always ?